# IntersectionObserver узнать нахождение наблюдаемого элемента

Tags: javascript

Как в IntersectionObserver, возможно узнать, что наблюдаемый элемент находится сверху линии пересечения?

Comment: в IntersectionObserver нет _линии_ пересечения, если область видимости при попадании в которую выставляется флаг [`.isIntersecting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/isIntersecting)

Comment: Не понимаю, isIntersecting срабатывает только тогда элемент пересекает... Это не показатель

Comment: Попробуй перечитать еще раз комментарий выше, там как раз и написано, что нет никакой линии пересечения